# Visual Studio - Making a copy of a project in the same solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, project

In Visual Studio 2010, I am trying to make a copy of a project and put it into the same solution.  I copied the files into a separate folder under the solution's folder in Windows Explorer, then did a copy-and-paste in VS from the original project to the new project.

When I run the solution from the original project, it works fine.  However, when I try to run it from the new project, it throws an exception:

```
Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Main'. This can
happen if the route that services this request ('{controller}/{action}/{id}')
does not specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the
request. If this is the case, register this route by calling an overload of
the 'MapRoute' method that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.

The request for 'Home' has found the following matching controllers:
TheCopiedProject.Controllers.MainController
TheOriginalProject.Controllers.MainController
```

I did a search on the copied project (Ctrl-Shift-F), but there are no references to the original project's namespace anywhere.

Apparently, I left something out - what do I need to do to fix this?